# Delete all rows in Access DB using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

This wont work but its as close as I can get, I am tring to delete all rows in table `Main`.

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connStr,sql;
    connStr = (@"SomeString");
    try {
        sql = "Delete from Main";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr));
        using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql));
        conn.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SetCon.Text = SetCon.Text + "Error " + ex + "\n
    }
}
```

It fails on lines:

```
conn.Open();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

It does not compile with the error `"does not exist in this context"`.

Comment: I get Connection property has not been initialized. on 'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();'    @Janes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr)){
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql);
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

When you're using `using` (yeah, English), then you have to define a scope in  which the object (here: `conn`) is valid. 

This scope is defined by `{ ... }` in which your following code is placed.

Writing `using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);` ends this scope right after `;` which means that following code will not have access to that object.

If you want to use `using` with your `OleDbCommand`, too, it should look like:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql))
    {                   
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

If you want to know more about `using`, see the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement):

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

In my last example, the scopes would look like this:[image: Scopes]

Where yellow resembles the scope of `conn` and orange resembles the scope of of `cmd1`.

If you want, you can call scope life time of the object, since it's marked as `Disposed` after.

Comment: I get Connection property has not been initialized. on 'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();'  @Janes Thanks for the blog post very comprehensive Ive modified my code using statments on your example and now back where I started

Comment: @Data: You have to pass your connection to the `OleDbCommand`, either by passing it via constructor (`OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)`) or by setting it via property 
`cmd1.Connection = conn;`. This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The C# `using` statement ensures that the `.Dispose()` method is called on the encapsulated `IDisposable` object when existing the proceeding code block.

As you have semi-colons straight after both of your `using` statements it's inferred that the scope of your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` are limited to that one line.

By removing the semi-colons and wrapping your operational statements in curved brackets, indicating the `using` scope, you can get your code to compile. Note that you can "stack" multiple using statements that share the same scope, as follows:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Further reading: [using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll need to look at how to use the "using" keyword. There should probably be a block statement following it containing parts of your code.